# What "stealth abilities" does the Papavero Stealth Edition have?

Tags: watch-dogs

The Car On-Demand app's description for Papavero Stealth Edition says

> A unique supercar with stealth abilities.

Uplay mentions a bit more

> Avoid detection and elude the cops in the Papavero Stealth Edition. ctOS won't know what hit it.

But that's still pretty vague. What are these stealth abilities and how do I make use of them?

Comment: Probably a smaller detection radius when you go in "stealth mode". I didn't want to use it cause it felt kind of wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sit inside the Papavery Stealth Edition, The CtOS scan percentage (time before they find you/the size of the bubble inside the yellow scan area) goes up much slower, and cools down much faster.
Compare a normal scan; where you have trouble outrunning the inner yellow bubble, where if they scan you while you sit in the Papavero you can drive at moderate speed and still stay outside the inner yellow bubble.
There is no changes to post-chase detection range or time (unless the minimap zoom fools me).